# Windows 8.1 installation hangs on configure step of gazebo code

Tags: gazebo, installation, windows

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, I am having trouble installing Gazebo on Windows 8.1. I have Visual Studio 2013 and have installed everything to the tee as described [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_on_windows&cat=install), and get as far as step 11, the configure step for the main gazebo code. What happens is cmake says  `Found ../../FreeImage-vc12-x64-release-debug/Source/FreeImage.h` and then it hangs forever (I left it on all night and nothing happened). I independently compiled FreeImage in VS2013 and tried again, but same thing happens.

How do I get past this?

Also please do not suggest running in virtual linux as I have tried and it it much too slow for me. And I can't dual boot into linux for other reasons pertaining to my project.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12633/windows-8.1-installation-hangs-on-configure-step-of-gazebo-code/) by [snakeplisk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2466/snakeplisk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [snakeplisk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2466/snakeplisk/) on 2016-02-17**:
Just tried with version 6.1 and the exact same thing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

EDIT: After a lot of playing around with this and getting nowhere, I asked on bitbucket and found someone who had already compiled it, and he was so kind as to branch his version with all edits included to get it to compile with VS2013

https://bitbucket.org/XB32Z/windows_gazebo7

Give it a try

---

Originally posted by [snakeplisk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2466/snakeplisk/) with karma: 3 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [snakeplisk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2466/snakeplisk/) on 2016-02-18**:
Now I've narrowed it down to protobuf, I had to replace the 2.6.0 vc12 version with 2.6.1 to get it to install in vs2013, now I get these linkage errors with protocompiler:

[ 16%] Linking CXX executable gazebomsgs_out.exe
GazeboGenerator.cc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virt

**Comment by [snakeplisk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2466/snakeplisk/) on 2016-02-18**:
Unresolved: google::protobuf::io::Printer::~Printer(void), public: void
__cdecl google::protobuf::io::Printer::Print , google::protobuf::compiler::cpp::GazeboGenerator::Generate,

**Comment by [snakeplisk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2466/snakeplisk/) on 2016-02-18**:
I know I'm pointing to the right lib files because it wouldnt even finish the configure stage without that

**Comment by [snakeplisk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2466/snakeplisk/) on 2016-02-18**:
http://pastebin.com/ahcpfCTc full error message

If anyone has the Windows compiled version can they please host a torrent or upload it to MEGA?

**Comment by [Gama11](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2531/gama11/) on 2016-03-30**:
I also had issues with Protobug during the configure step (see [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/issues/52/windows-installation-fails-during#comment-None)). I ended up solving it by downgrading CMake from 3.5.1 to 3.2.0. Now I'm stuck on "NMAKE : fatal error U1077" for the next command though...

**Comment by [TwoBid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2562/twobid/) on 2016-04-21**:
Had the same issue. Isnt there someone who solved it or can help?